# How to do a parallel execution in bdd cucumber with Junit

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, bdd

I there any possibilities to do parallel execution in BDD cucumber framework using JUnit

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cucumber with JUnit 5, you can add `cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=true` to the `junit-platform.properties` file.

For more control on the number of threads you can use some extra options [from the documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine):

```
cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=                          # true or false.
                                                              # default: false

cucumber.execution.parallel.config.strategy=                  # dynamic, fixed or custom.
                                                              # default: dynamic

cucumber.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=         # positive integer.
                                                              # example: 4

cucumber.execution.parallel.config.dynamic.factor=            # positive double.
                                                              # default: 1.0
```

If you don't have a working example of Cucumber with JUnit 5 start with the [cucumber-java-skeleton](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton).